# How can I get plaintext password from spring-security?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-ldap

I use Grails + spring-security + LDAP to authenticate users. The authentication works now but I need the plain text password to authenticate a second service.

I tried the SpringSecurityService properties but none contains the password.

Do I have to implement my own UserDetailsMapper or does the LdapUserDetailsMapper also provide the mapping of the plain text password retrieved from the web form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the credentials from the `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder`. However, I really don't think it is a good idea to use this. You will not be able to use the 'remember-me' nor the 'run-as' or 'switch-user' functionality, because thne the credentials would not contain the current user's password (they will probably be null). Also, I don't think you would get the plaintext password if using anything other than basic HTML authentication or form authentication.

Anyhow, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()` will get you the plaintext password if using form authentication.

Comment: There is an `erase-credentials` setting for spring security. Setting it to false may help retrieve the password. However, I have no idea where this setting goes. I'm looking for where to put the setting and found this post.

Comment: Found it. Try adding to Config.groovy: `grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerManager.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = false`